# Ubuntu 18.04 ppa.launchpad.net/george-edison55/cmake-3.x/ubuntu bionic Release 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-18.04

Hi i wanted to fix this error

```
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND
```

I searched on the internet and tried this two solution

1. get build-essential

   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential

2.tryna insall g++

```
 apt-get install g++
```

However i get this error

```
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/george-edison55/cmake-3.x/ubuntu bionic Release                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
```

And i get it on every update i do.
I followed the solution given  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031756/ubuntu-18-04-cannot-update) but always have the same problem.
I tried many others ways but always fail.

Can someone help me fix this error please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 already comes with cmake 3.10.

The ppa you are using is for older ubuntu versions and you don't need it in 18.04 version.

If you added it by mistake you can remove it by using:

`ppa-purge`

Check how to use it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) , for more derail.

Comment: so what to do ?

Comment: do you remember what you have done so far? If so, you need to undo these.

Comment: i did that sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential how to undo this

Comment: You have added some ppa or something that need to be removed

Comment: Yes true u can show how to remove it that others may take benefices from

Comment: I would do it with ppa-purge. 
Please see here for more details
https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed

Comment: yes true i do know how but just that i wanted that once other have same issue and read your answer will find it complete and sufficient to solve the pb and avoid search again.

Answer (score 5):

You can remove this ppa by using below command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x
```

Comment: This is helpful to fix my issue